# concatenate a variable name with lang method variable name in php

Tags: php

okay i have the following scenario:

```
<?php echo sprintf(lang('produkt_titel'), $replace_text);?>
```

i have a **lang file** which has languages text using key value pair.
the value of `$replace_text` is **"Instagram Followers"** and i want to access a key from **lang file** which is **"Instagram_Followers_produkt_titel"**. i want to concatenate `produkt_titel'` with `$replace_text` variable value with underscore so how can i do it in php? i have attached the 3 screenshots in which i am showing data and fetching data and the lang file.

[image: this is code image]

[image: this is where to display the value]

[image: this is where the lang code is]

Comment: If you can change `lang('key', [, string|array])` to accept params, it could interpolate the variables you pass it (think sprintf) then could then use `%` or `{{key}}` etc to inject values inbetween strings instead of concatenation, else your lang file is going to become unmaintainable, also placement of variables and/or sentence structure might be different for different langs so concatenations of words wont always read well, crude example, https://3v4l.org/e1nEB

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities depending on what you want.  To just access `ebike_produkt_titel` from `lang()`:

```
echo lang("{$replace_text}_produkt_titel");
```

To get a result from `lang()` for `produkt_titel` and concatenate with `$replace_text`:

```
echo $replace_text . lang("_produkt_titel");
```

Comment: I'm certain the first is what he wants, since it's a translation function.

Comment: let me edit my question a bit more to give more specific details.

Comment: can you check the screenshots now?

Comment: Yes, but you would need to show the `lang()` function.  If it is returning the array element then it should work.

Comment: how can i do it? can you help me in that?

Comment: Not sure, not enough info, should work https://3v4l.org/slYQ1